# How to enable billing to GCP project using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I am trying to enable billing for GCP projects using terraform but the project was created using GCP console.

I am getting error like project already exists, Is there any way to enable project using terraform for existing project ?

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {

  name       = "ML Cluster"
  project_id = "ml-cluster"
  org_id     = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  billing_account = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [import your existing project](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) into the Terraform state first, so that the imported project has the correct identifier (`google_project.my_project`). Once that's done, you can apply your Terraform configuration to enable billing for the project.